# AdSense and AngularJS application -- approval

Tags: angularjs, ajax, adsense

My website is a Single Page Application written with AngularJs.

I am trying to add AdSense for some pages. After submitting, my site was rejected because of the following reason: "Insufficient Content".

My question here is: were adSense crawlers able to access and view my website considering that we use escaped_frangment and phantomJs to render the pages? (This works pretty fine for google bots.)

What can I doto make my website approved by adSense?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Prerender](https://prerender.io/) successfully in the past. It was a bit of a pain to set up, but works very nicely.

> Search engines and social networks are always trying to crawl your
>   pages, but they only see the javascript tags...
>
> We render your javascript in a browser, save the static HTML, and you
>   return that to the crawlers!